# Python data structures 2D lists

Tags: python, data-structures

Here is the question:

Create a function that takes a grid of # and -, where each hash (#) represents a mine and each dash (-) represents a mine-free spot.
Return a grid, where each dash is replaced by a digit, indicating the number of mines immediately adjacent to the spot i.e. (horizontally, vertically, and diagonally).

Example of an input:

[ ["-", "-", "-", "#", "#"], ["-", "#", "-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "#", "-", "-"], ["-", "#", "#", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"] ]

Example of the expected output:

[ ["1", "1", "2", "#", "#"], ["1", "#", "3", "3", "2"], ["2", "4", "#", "2", "0"], ["1", "#", "#", "2", "0"], ["1", "2", "2", "1", "0"] ]

Use deep copy to copy your input grid to get the desired output grid, but *leave your input grid look as the original* copy **(no changes).**

The question is how to do it - in the deepcopy way?

Below is my code:

```
def mines_adj(grid):
    n = len(grid)
    if(n == 0):
        return
    directions = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1], [-1, -1], [-1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 1]]
    m = len(grid[0])
    newgrid = [["#" for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
    for r in range(n):
        for c in range(m):
            if(grid[r][c] == "-"):
                count = 0
                for dir in directions:
                    nr = r + dir[0]
                    nc = c + dir[1]
                    if(nr >= 0 and nr < n and nc >=0 and nc < m and grid[nr][nc] == "#"):
                        count = count + 1
                newgrid[r][c] = count
    return newgrid
# making grid given in input
grid = [["-", "-", "-", "#", "#"],
        ["-", "#", "-", "-", "-"],
        ["-", "-", "#", "-", "-"],
        ["-", "#", "#", "-", "-"],
        ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]]

newgrid = mines_adj(grid)
print(newgrid)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use *deepcopy* to do the operations (aka, count mines neighbors cells), but leave the original grid *intact*.  If this is true, you're almost there - the codes *almost* works fine.

So here I just suggest some *minor* improvements along the way to do the *deepcopy*.

Please ask questions if any parts is not clear.

```
from itertools import product
from copy import deepcopy

G =    [ ["-", "-", "-", "#", "#"],
         ["-", "#", "-", "-", "-"],
         ["-", "-", "#", "-", "-"],
         ["-", "#", "#", "-", "-"],
         ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]]

expected = [["1", "1", "2", "#", "#"],
            ["1", "#", "3", "3", "2"],
            ["2", "4", "#", "2", "0"],
            ["1", "#", "#", "2", "0"],
            ["1", "2", "2", "1", "0"] ]


def mines_adj(grid):
    row = len(grid)
    col = len(grid[0]) 
   
    if(row == 0):  return -1

    directions = list(product([0, 1, -1], repeat=2))
    #directions = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1], [-1, -1], [-1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 1]]

    newgrid = deepcopy(grid)    # <--- make a *new* copy
    #newgrid = [["#" for j in range(col)] for i in range(row)]
    
    for r in range(row):
        for c in range(col):
            
            if(grid[r][c] == "-"):
                count = 0
                for dirs in directions:
                    nr = r + dirs[0]
                    nc = c + dirs[1]
                    
                    if 0 <= nr < row and  \
                       0 <= nc < col and grid[nr][nc] == "#":
                        count += 1
                newgrid[r][c] = str(count)  # seems u want str(count)
                
    return newgrid


out = mines_adj(G)
assert out == expected           # silence - because it's the same
```

Output:  (to confirm the original grid is the same w/o changes)

```
for row in G: print(row)
```

Comment: here's the feedback you asked for. I'd started to code my own Minesweeper in the past and it followed exactly the same logic. If it is a good thing or not is not me to decide :P One little thing: I wouldn't use the expression `dir` in the loop, because it is also a build-in function.

Comment: Thanks.  @Rabinzel - noted.  Feedback needed because I'm not sure I got OP's question covered.  Feel better now... Appreciate it.